# Google adwords conversion tracking

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1, google-analytics

We have recently set up a magento community site running 1.9.0.1 having moved from go.

We are trying to set up the google adwords conversion tracking, there is a piece of code that they want placing on the success page.

Where is this located in 1.9.0.1?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As 
Step1:

you need to add conversion code on ordee success file

```
app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtemplate/template/checkout/success.phtml
```

if file no exits then:

copy `success.phtml` from

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/
```

and pasted

```
app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtemplate/template/checkout/
```

add your `code on new success.phtml`

in this file you can order id using below code

```
$this->getOrderId()
```

**OR:**
check this extension
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/luka-google-adwords-conversion-tracking.html

Comment: The line

var google_conversion_value = 1.00;

in the google conversion code, does that not give all transactions a value of 1?

Comment: @PeterO'Sullivan Yes it does. You need to replace that with the transaction value.

Comment: GitHub link for Luka extension https://github.com/lukanetconsult/mage-google-adwords , works perfect.

Answer (score 7):

You can copy and paste the following piece of code in your **success.phtml**

**/app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtemplate/template/checkout/success.phtml**

```
<?php
$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
$total = (float)number_format($order()->getSubtotal(),2);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 'CONVERSION_ID';
var google_conversion_language = "LANG_CODE";
var google_conversion_format = "FORMAT";
var google_conversion_color = "COLOR";
var google_conversion_label = "LABEL";
if (<?php echo $total?>) {
    var google_conversion_value = <?php echo $total?>;
}
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt=""
src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/CONVERSION_ID/?value=<?php echo $total?>&amp;label=LABEL&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
```

Make sure you change the following variables in the above code -:

- `CONVERSION_ID` (e.g. `999999999`)
- `LANG_CODE` (e.g. `en`)
- `FORMAT` (e.g. `1`)
- `COLOR` (e.g. `#ffffff`)
- `LABEL` (e.g. `-9C8CICMuggQ4O_B1wM`)

If you are not confident regarding the above approach then you can use the following module which would easy to configure instead of fiddling around with the code

[http://www.scommerce-mage.co.uk/magento-google-adwords-conversion-tracking.html](http://www.scommerce-mage.co.uk/magento-google-adwords-conversion-tracking.html#.VOzbtC6xWao)

Hope it helps!

Comment: `$order` in the code above is undefined. Here's a fix:

`$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();`

`$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);`

`$total = (float) number_format($order->getSubtotal(), 2); `

Comment: @PartialOrder - Thanks, it has been fixed now in the post above.

Answer (score 1):

this is the code which worked for me

```
<?php
//Get Order Number & Order Total
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId());
$amount = number_format($order->getGrandTotal(),2);
```

?>

and i got it from this link, maybe it helps someone aswell.

http://www.jxtgroup.com/how-to-setup-conversion-tracking-in-magento_3912881.html